# oidc-client frame error when manually calling signingSilent

Tags: angular, identityserver4, oidc-client-js, angular-auth-oidc-client

A bit of a strange one. On my Angular app, I have a `refreshUser` method to get the possibly logged in user loaded before displaying all the screen data. To do so I have the following `ngOnInit` method:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.authService.refreshUser();
}
```

the refreshUser method has the following code:

```
public refreshUser(): Promise<void> {
        return this.manager.signinSilent()
                            .then(user => {
                                this.user = user;
                            })
                            .catch(e => {
                                console.log('User not logged in', e);
                            });
    }
```

On a brand new navigation this works smoothly and I get the error:

```
User not logged in ErrorResponse: login_required
    at new e (main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1)
    at t._processSigninParams (main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1)
    at t.validateSigninResponse (main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1)
    at main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1
    at e.invoke (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1)
    at e.invoke (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
    at t.run (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
    at polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
```

(the user has never logged in).

The strange scenario is that if I have the user that has logged in, I close the web browser and the open it up again, the screen hangs for around 10 seconds then I get another error:

```
main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1 User not logged in Error: Frame window timed out
   at t._error (main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1)
   at t._timeout (main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1)
   at e.invokeTask (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
   at Object.onInvokeTask (main.2a53201b6340bff6258a.js:1)
   at e.invokeTask (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
   at t.runTask (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
   at t.invokeTask (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
   at invoke (polyfills.3efb6da5a4e032fb1cf9.js:1)
```

But when the screen loads and I click on "Log in" (since the user wasn't) then the "classic" AuthGuard gets triggered before loading the component so I run the standard `startAuthentication()`:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        }
        this.authService.startAuthentication();
        return false;
    }
```

which quickly logs the user in. My question is: What's the difference between that function and the signingSilent function in terms of signing in the user? Because it does however the behavior is not the expected, at least in terms of timings and user experience. I want to be able to "log the user in if that was possible but do not prompt the log in screen". Does that make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to verify the network call and access the token that is being passed along with singin silent call, I'm doubting that your token is expired. signinsilent call carries the current ID token to the server. 

10 seconds is the defaults signinSilent callback timeout, if the call response is not received in 10 seconds, then the oidc-client code will emit the frame timed out error.

Comment: Weirdly that’s not the issue. It seems the user was logged in two different applications which share the same instance of identity

Comment: Are they deployed under the same domain?

Comment: Yes, would that be an issue?

Comment: Nope, as long as maintain tokens at a central place like local storage. otherwise, if the user works on two applications in two different tabs, then things will get wacky if we don't maintain tokens same across both tabs. 

secondly, we ran into a weird issue with actual sign-in cookie expiration time. .net does not slide cookie to new extension time unless the current cookie expiration time is past half of the old expiration time by the time of renewal. 

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2796